# React Redux TS: TypeScript complains about a connect() call

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I've spent hours trying to figure out why doesn't TypeScript like my connect() call and I can't do it because the error message is kind of cryptic (like many TypeScript warnings are) and the Redux definitions file is pretty complex as well. Here's my .tsx file:

```
import { addTodo, removeTodo } from "@test-shared/redux";
import { IAppState, ITodoItem } from "@test-shared/types";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import uuid from "uuid/v4";
import TodoAdder from "./TodoAdder";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

interface ITodosProps {
  saveTodo: (todo: ITodoItem) => void;
  deleteTodo: (id: string) => void;
  todos: ITodoItem[];
}

/**
 * List and add new Todos
 * @param props
 */
function Todos(props: ITodosProps): JSX.Element {
  const { saveTodo, deleteTodo, todos } = props;

  /**
   * On Todo remove handler
   * @param id
   */
  const onRemove = (id: string) => {
    deleteTodo(id);
  };

  /**
   * On Todo add handler
   * @param text
   */
  const onAdd = (text: string) => {
    const todo = { id: uuid(), text };

    // Save to state
    saveTodo(todo);
  };

  return (
    <TodosView>
      <TodosItems>
        <TodoList todos={todos} onRemove={onRemove} />
      </TodosItems>
      <TodoAdderWrapper>
        <TodoAdder onAdd={onAdd} />
      </TodoAdderWrapper>
    </TodosView>
  );
}

const ConnectedTodos = connect(
  (state: IAppState) => ({
    todos: state.items
  }),
  (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    deleteTodo: (id: string) => {
      dispatch(removeTodo(id));
    },
    saveTodo: (todo: ITodoItem) => {
      dispatch(addTodo(todo));
    }
  })
)(Todos);

export default ConnectedTodos;

const TodosView = styled.View`
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
`;

const TodoAdderWrapper = styled.View`
  flex-grow: 0;
`;

const TodosItems = styled.View`
  flex-grow: 1;
`;
```

TypeScript is complaining about the connect() call, here's the error:

```
Argument of type '(props: ITodosProps) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
  Type '(props: ITodosProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<never>'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I pasted the code into a file and wasn't able to reproduce the error on the `connect` call, likely because I don't have the other imported files from your project.  If you'd like my help, you'll need to provide enough code to reproduce the problem, either by manually combining the relevant code into a single snippet or by publishing a repository that I can download.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
const Todos: React.SFC<ITodosProps> = (props) => {
// your code here
}
```

It's hard to help without the full code though.